# Regex to match error between 2 lines that contain ##

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression, logs

I have the follwing log file.. that contains `some_error_message`. If `some_error_message` occurs between two lines that contain `##` (echoed as "`##`"), we consider it as error occured in remote ftp/sftp site.

```
some content in log file..
##
some content in log file..

some_error_message

some content in log file..
##
some content in log file..
```

Now, I want to write regex to match `some_error_message` between lines containing sybols `##`

Below is just a sample

```
grep -iq "^[#][#].*some_error_message.*[#][#]$"
```

Please help!!

Note: There will be only exactly 4 symbols of # in logs. No more. ## in one line, ## in another line.

Comment: Are those `##` lines always pairwise? Thus, if there are four such lines, you care for messages between first and second, between third and fourth, but not between second and third? Maybe you can extend your example accordingly.

Comment: In your example you show one #, not two...

Comment: The logs contains only four # signs. ## in one line, ## in another line. that's it.

Comment: How do you identify that it is indeed an error?

Comment: some_error_message is actually: 'No such files or directory' when ftp/sftp throws this error.

Answer (score 2):

Tools like `grep` only match one line at a time, so you can't really match the whole thing with a single regular expression while using `grep`.

You can use a tool like `sed` to extract only the part within the nested block, then pipe that to `grep` to look for the error message you're interested in.

The `/START/,/END/p` command in `sed` will only print lines between a block starting and ending with lines matching the two regexps. Additionally, you should pass `sed` a `-n` argument, so it doesn't print any lines by default.

So:

```
$ sed -n '/^##$/,/^##$/p' mylogfile.txt |
  grep -iq '^some_error_message$'
```

Comment: Thank You @filbranden This is working. And I will also try to see if I find any luck with grep -E

Answer (score 2):

Perl easily handles this with its [range](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator, sometimes referred to as the `flip-flop` operator:

```
perl -nle 'if (/^##/.../^##/) {print if /some_error_message/i}' file
```

This reads your file, looking for a block that both begins and ends with `##` anchored to the beginning of a line. Within the block, any line with the token `some_error_message` is then printed. In this example, the "some_error_messsage" is matched case insensitively.

Comment: thank You for the answer. This is also working. We may prefer grep, sed over perl just to use default commands instead of invoking perl.

Answer (score 1):

Simple version, just `sed` (typically you don't need to pipe `sed` output, just concatenate commands with `;`):

```
sed '/^##$/,//!d;/some_error_message/!d'
```

First, we create an address range from `^##$` (a line of just `##`) to an empty pattern (which means: repeat the last pattern, thus again a `##` line). Invert the match with `!` and `d` delete everything outside the range.

Secondly, `d`elete all lines not (`!`) containing the `some_error_message`.